# How to make the dark mode effect hit the circles designed with css

Tags: html, css

I'm using this dark mode toggle that affect all the text plus the background color and when I click on it the colors they switch. But I have a problem with the circles that I've designed. I'd like the dark mode affect the background color of them, having the background inside the circles "lime" on the black background and viceversa. Here's the code and the link to the page:

https://civitonia.com/26993899

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="inner">
 <a href="https://civitonia.cargo.site/26977363"><div class="circle" style="background-image:url('https://freight.cargo.site/t/original/i/655f74e74d3b88cc9d367ba8cccd79680c3837a84a547f9e03b6f39981f424e0/3.png');"></div></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Chiara Bersani <br> Marta Montanini</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

DARK MODE CSS:

```
.colorOuterSVG {
  color: black;
  margin-top: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em
}

.colorOuterSVG .dark { display: none }
.colorOuterSVG .light { display: block }
.dark-mode .colorOuterSVG {color:#d9ff76!important; }
.dark-mode .colorOuterSVG .dark { display: block }
.dark-mode .colorOuterSVG .light { display: none }
.colorSVG { display: block }
.colorSVG path { fill: currentColor }

.dark-mode {
  background-color: black!important;
  color: #d9ff76!important;
}

.dark-mode button {
    color: black!important;
    background-color: #d9ff76;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: solid 1px #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

THE CIRCLES MADE WITH CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 980px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.cell {
  flex-basis: 33.3%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-items : flex-start 
}

.cell:before {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

.circle {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 0.5px solid; 
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
  background-color: #d9ff76!important;
}

.circle img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.inner {
  text-align: start;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
}
```

Right now I've set up a background color for the circles and if I take it away the background will stay lime on lime and black on black!

Answer (score 2):

Add this css code for dark mode :

```
.dark-mode .circle {
 background-color: #000 !important;
}
```